# Why doesn't Riddick know he's Furyan?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-chronicles-of-riddick

In the extended cut (video version) of *The Chronicles of Riddick*, while Riddick is on his way from the Planet U.V. going to the Helion system, we see a dream (?? don't know what to call her ??) which Riddick is having about his home world of Furya. It seems to me he doesn't really know what it's about or about his heritage. Is there a reason for this? Is it a repressed memory? **Why does it seem Riddick doesn't know he's Furyan?** Is there any back story on this which I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Furyans are said to be a highly spiritual (warrior) race. The dream was a vision. We do know though that Riddick also carries repressed memories.

From [Wikia](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Richard_B._Riddick#Early_Life):

> While Riddick retained memories of massacre on Furya, **these memories were repressed and forgotten, likely due to his extreme youth at the time**. Instead, he believed his mother attempted to kill him at birth by strangling him with his umbilical cord and dumping him in a liquour store trash bin, likely the story contained in his records and just as likely told to him repeatedly by those with little care for the child Riddick's sense of self worth.
>
> As Riddick grew older **he began recieving [sic] periodic visions of a Furyan named Shirah**; visions which he believed to be signs of mental instability. It would not be until his encounter with the Necromongers that his repressed memories would finally escape their imprisonment and he would realize that he had a homeworld and a tragic past that he had never been consciously aware of.

A lot of the backstory is from the [Riddick games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:The_Chronicles_of_Riddick_video_games).

Comment: Very good out take there. Says a lot and sums up what I was thinking, but couldn't quite put together. Part of the film also shows us when his "shadow" memory changes to a real memory and he sees the Lord Marshall as the destructor of his world. I didn't know whether this was a vision memory given to him by Shirah or if it was a suppressed memory.